# Integrating jQuery Auto Height with Views Infinite Scroll

Tags: 8, views

I have a views block with an infinite scroll (using [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) and [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) modules). The block displays cards and I want them to have the same height. [jQuery Auto Height](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_height) does that well. However, it only happens for the initial load. Auto Height has no way of knowing to fire on subsequent Ajax calls. What is the best way to integrate them so that Auto Height is called on each infinite scroll Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [source](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/auto_height/-/blob/8.x-1.x/js/init-autoheight.js) for the jQuery Auto height module, there appears to be an `AutoHeight()` method that you can call on a given jQuery object.

```
$(drupalSettings.auto_height.selectors).AutoHeight();
```

And in the [source](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_infinite_scroll/-/blob/8.x-1.x/js/infinite-scroll.js) for Views Infinite Scroll, we can see that an event, `scroll.views_infinite_scroll`, is available to listen in on. The portion of Views Infinite Scroll's code that invokes this event is:

```
$window.on(scrollEvent, debounce(function () {
  if (isLoadNeeded()) {
    $pager.find('[rel=next]').click();
    $window.off(scrollEvent);
  }
}, 200));
```

Using the above as a template, I think you could invoke the `AutoHeight()` method every time a new view is added.